# Docker doesn't know a shared path

Tags: docker

I am running a custom app that spans a docker container. when try to run it I get following error:

`The path /etc/localtime is not shared from OS X and is not known to Docker.`

Many online links indicate that I need this path shared in docker. I already have /users, /volume, /private, /tmp already shared. /etc comes under /private so why it is not already shared?

I have this: `/etc/localtime -> /var/db/timezone/zoneinfo/America/New_York`

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: https://github.com/docker/for-mac/issues/2396

Comment: I have already tried that and it still doesn't work